# make recursive cte using view

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

Since I am using MySQL lower than version 8, I cannot use CTE.

So I am trying to make CTE by view and it works.
But recursive CTE is challenging me.

I want to transform recursive CTE below into view base query.

Is there a way?

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count(n)
AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM cte_count
    WHERE n < 3
    )
SELECT n
FROM cte_count;
```

Comment: MySQL prior to version 8 supports neither CTEs nor recursive CTEs.

Comment: If you can give us some sample data and the output you expect, maybe a workaround can be suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following appears to do what you want:

```
create view v_cte_count as
    select 1 as n union all
    select 2 as n;
```

I see no advantage to using a recursive CTE for this in any database.